# make a list of matrices from a list of data

Tags: python, list, matrix

I have a hypothetical list of data from a .txt document

0    1    2
3    4    5
6    7    8
(value)

I want to make 2 lists of matricies like this

```
list 1            list 2
[0, 1, 2]         [[0],[1],[2]]
[3, 4, 5]         [[3],[4],[5]]
[6, 7, 8]         [[6],[7],[8]]
```

Each item in list 1 must be able to give me a dot product when multiplying by a previously declared matrix.

```
new list 1
dot([0,1,2],mat)
dot([3,4,5],mat)
dot([6,7,8],mat)
```

I have tried appending the 3 values from the .txt document into a list as a matrix (this was done within a for loop)

```
list1.append ([value[0], value[1], value[2]]
```

but it didn't work. It gave me an error.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where are you getting `dot` from? it's not native to Python -- do you want help writing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may achieve it via *list comprehension* as:

```
>>> my_string = '0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8'
>>> row = 3
>>> my_list = my_string.split() # split the string based on space ' '

>>> list_1 = [my_list[i*3:(i*3)+row] for i in range(row)]
>>> list_1 # Output for example 1
[['0', '1', '2'], 
 ['3', '4', '5'], 
 ['6', '7', '8']]

>>> list_2 = [[[c] for c in my_list[i*3:(i*3)+row]] for i in range(row)]
>>> list_2 # Ouput for example 2
[[['0'], ['1'], ['2']], 
 [['3'], ['4'], ['5']], 
 [['6'], ['7'], ['8']]]
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can see you forgot a bracket,

This:

```
list1.append ([value[0], value[1], value[2]]
```

Should be:

```
list1.append ([value[0], value[1], value[2]])
```

Edit: This answer is probably not the one you are looking for, as i am reading the post the problem does not seem to be the error, but something else.
It is not really clear what your question is. Maybe you could add some complete code instead of just samples to better explain the problem.